# How do I read response header from RestTemplate when response code is 403

Tags: java, android, spring, resttemplate, robospice

I am using RoboSpiceManger for APIs, I am able to read/get the response headers for status code is 200 for POST requests using RestTemplate like this:

```
      ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = (ResponseEntity<?>) obj;
        String token =responseEntity.getHeaders().getFirst("some_token_key");
```

But I am unable to read/get the header if the status code is 403. It is giving only SpiceException and I am unable to read the response header in this situation.

Comment: Status code 403 indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. Meaning, the API call you are making, server is unable to authorize it. !!

Comment: Yes, and with that status code I am getting a header value which i need to use in the next going request. So, I need to read/get the header value for 403 situation as well.

Comment: Try using `HttpHeaders headers = responseEntity.getHeaders()`, and iterate each, to see what exactly there in the headers.

Comment: Yes, did the same thing but I am getting headers only for 200 status code but not 403. It is entering into "RequestListener<Object>" Failure method and it has only 1 parameter -  SpiceException.

Comment: Could you show the stack trace in your question??

Comment: An exception occurred during request network execution :403 
                                                                                    org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 
                                                                                        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:76)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172492/discussion-between-mad-man-and-arvindlal-jaiswal).